# Change a script element's src attribute during a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following html code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="http://localhost:8086/a/b/myLib.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script>
    myLib.displayAlert("Yoog");
</script>
</html>
```

I added a break point before I call the `myLib.displayAlert` function and I want to change the `src` of the script to another one from the `src`: http://localhost:8086/a/b/c/myLib.js.

Is there a way to dynamically change the `src` script so that when I continue the program, I will get a different implementation to the `myLib.displayAlert`?

Comment: No. By the time you've hit the breakpoint, the code is already in memory and running.

Comment: Indeed, don't rely on breakpoint. If your code doesn't work normally, I just won't work. Stop trying to seek for workaround version, seek solution instead.